# RTK Query direct update mutation cache data

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

My application require login to use, and I will call `useLoginMutation({fixedCacheKey: 'userInfo'})` to call related API.

The API will return the token and other variable for example `isDrawerOpen`.

In Redux DevTools:

```
api: {
    queries: {},
    mutations: {
      userInfo: {
        requestId: 'xxxxxxxxx',
        status: 'fulfilled',
        endpointName: '/login',
        startedTimeStamp: 999999999999,
        data: {
          accessToken: 'tokenXXX',
          isDrawerOpen: false,
        },
        fulfilledTimeStamp: 999999999999
      }
    },
    provided: {},
    subscriptions: {},
    config: {}
}
```

Then, the UI is reading the `isDrawerOpen` to render the drawer. When the user open the drawer in UI, `POST` request will be called and return the success status.

The problem is as follow:

As my understanding, RTK Quest example will tell me to re-POST the get the latest `userInfo`. However, `'/login'` POST is not only return the latest `isDrawerOpen`, but also `accessToken` which I do not need.

Therefore, I would like to update `isDrawerOpen` directly in RTK cache. I have tried `updateQueryData` but it seems to be used in `useQuery` but not `useMutation`. Is there anyway to direct control the cache in `mutations`?